# Cannot get FB.ui (share/feed) to work - lack knowledge/understanding

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying for 2 days to get a button on my website to open up a pre-populated facebook message for the user to post to their timeline. From the reading I've done it seems that the 'Feed' method no longer supports a custom message, but I think 'Share' does ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share?locale=en_GB))?

Nevertheless, I can't get it to actually work anyway. I have set up an app on facebook to get an appId; I've also used the code given directly by facebook developer site but to no avail.

I would like this button to trigger a pre-populated (let's say, "this is a test") facebook message to pop up:

```
<a id="fb-share"><img src="images/fb-logo.png" /></a>
```

The code I've simply copied direct from my app page on facebook dev is:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxMyappIDxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

So then I believe the remaining script is to call the fb.ui share method from a click of the #fb-share button, so this is what I've got:

```
<script>
$('#fb-share').click(function ()
{
    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://mywebsite.com',
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  }
)
});
</script>
```

I am also aware this is meant to share a link and not a message; through all my searching I've not found how to actually define a custom message. Fully prepared for being told this is an embarrassing excuse of an attempt, but help will be very much welcomed!

Cheers
Pinchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...pre-populated facebook message...

The rest is irrelevant, it´s not possible and not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Additional Information: The Share dialog only takes a link as parameter, you can´t change anything else. It takes the rest of the data from the Open Graph Tags of that link and you can´t prefill the message.

Comment: Fair enough! Bollocks to that idea then... That said, even the above doesn't work to post a link - any ideas what;s wrong with it?

Comment: Just found the share URL tool. Will use that to share a link to the site. Thank you for the info. 2 days of my life wasted... :P